# Rails generate model error message - No value provided for required options '--orm'

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I tried to generate a model using Rails 3.1.3

```
rails generate model Blob twit:string
```

and I got this error message

```
No value provided for required options '--orm'
```

I'm trying to add a few things to this Ruby Twitter gem https://github.com/sferik/sign-in-with-twitter, so I don't really know if a gem in this gemfile (which I didn't create) is needing these options..

Is there something in my Gemfile that requires me to complete these required options and what are those options?

update: there was no database.yml file in the config folder, so (after reading one of the comments) I took one from another project and included it to use sqlite3 but it hasn't fixed the problem

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails', '~> 3.1.0'

gem 'haml', '~> 3.2.0.alpha'
gem 'omniauth-twitter'
gem 'twitter'

platforms :jruby do
  gem 'jruby-openssl'
end

group :assets do
  gem 'sass-rails'
  gem 'uglifier'
end

gem 'sqlite3'

group :production do

  gem 'thin'
end

group :test do
  gem 'mocha'
  gem 'simplecov'
  gem 'webmock'
end
```

database.yml

```
# SQLite version 3.x
#   gem install sqlite3
#
#   Ensure the SQLite 3 gem is defined in your Gemfile
#   gem 'sqlite3'
development:
  adapter: sqlite3
  database: db/development.sqlite3
  pool: 5
  timeout: 5000

# Warning: The database defined as "test" will be erased and
# re-generated from your development database when you run "rake".
# Do not set this db to the same as development or production.
test: &test
  adapter: sqlite3
  database: db/test.sqlite3
  pool: 5
  timeout: 5000

production:
  adapter: sqlite3
  database: db/production.sqlite3
  pool: 5
  timeout: 5000
```

Update..this is the top of my config/application.rb file. Instead of doing require 'all' (as my other rails apps do)it's only requiring a few selected files...

```
require File.expand_path('../boot', __FILE__)

require 'action_controller/railtie'
require 'rails/test_unit/railtie'
require 'sprockets/railtie'

if defined?(Bundler)
  # If you precompile assets before deploying to production, use this line
  Bundler.require(*Rails.groups(:assets => %w(development test)))
  # If you want your assets lazily compiled in production, use this line
  # Bundler.require(:default, :assets, Rails.env)
end

module SignInWithTwitter
```

Comment: Change your database.yml to use sqlite

Comment: @user458221 there is no database.yml file in my config folder...any suggestions?

Comment: @user458221 I took a database.yml from another project that uses sqlite3 and put it in config folder but I'm getting the same message. see OP for database.yml. Any help would be appreciated..

Comment: Did you accidentally / on purpose take out Active Record from the list of things that Rails uses? Show us the top of your `config/application.rb` file please. That should tell us enough.

Comment: @Ryan Bigg, see OP or update. It doesn't do a require 'all' (as my other rails apps do) but rather only selected files...I assume this is the problem?? I'm playing around with https://github.com/sferik/sign-in-with-twitter

Comment: there should be `require 'rails/all'` in your application.rb file. I see only requires of some specific stuff, but rails or activerecord isn't loaded at all.

Comment: Yes you did remove it. You cannot generate models if you're not using a gem that doesn't provide ORM functionality for Rails.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're missing this line from `config/application.rb`:

```
require 'active_record/railtie'
```

This will load ActiveRecord when your Rails application starts up, providing the ORM functionality for it that it needs for the generator.

If you don't want to use ActiveRecord, then you should look into DataMapper or even something like Mongoid if NoSQL databases are what floats your boat.

Comment: any benefit to doing that over doing 'rails/all'?

Comment: Not really, `rails/all` simply requires all of Rails, which may not be what you want. All the `rails/all` require line does is require this file: https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/3-1-stable/railties/lib/rails/all.rb